# change content of uiwebview div object

Tags: iphone, uiwebview

is there any way to change the content of uiwebview in iphone application? by using div or else.

my problem is that, to append data to uiwebview at any time. it think it can be done by replacing div content?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can change like this

```
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('divtagId').innerHTML ='%@';",newContent]];
```