# Stop UIWebView from loading a specific image using its 'id'

Tags: iphone, html, c, ios

Hi I would like to stop UIWebView from loading a specific image, the problem is that the images url changes, BUT its id (id="Header1_headerimg") stays the same.

The html on the web page:

```
< img alt="Equestria Daily" height="350px; " id="Header1_headerimg" src="http://4.bp.blogspot.com/-WS5XLbTi47E/ThdWHuLoR4I/AAAAAAAAHT8/cdqXIVfXB9k/s1600/newdefaultbannerappstra.png" style="display: block" width="1100px; ">
```

I want this blocked in UIWebView.

No I cannot edit the pages html.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[I think this would answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459488/change-content-of-uiwebview-div-object)

```
[webview stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"document.getElementById('Header1_headerimg').style.display='none'"]];
```

Comment: Sorry if this seams like a stupid question but where would I put this?

Comment: Right after you call `loadRequest:`
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766627/uiwebview-stringbyevaluatingjavascriptfromstring-not-changing-text-box-value)

Comment: You can find all the apps code at http://bottlelife.co.uk/app/ but the file I think needs editing is WebViewController.m found at http://bottlelife.co.uk/app/Classes/WebViewController.m