# How To Make UIWebView's Content Bigger

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad

I'm making a little app, and there's a small UIWebView there. The problem is that I need to make the content on it look either smaller or bigger. For example, text (like this) should be bigger or smaller. Before asking this question, I tried this:

```
[web setScalesPageToFit:YES];
[web setFrame:size];
```

It doesn't have the behavior I want. Any ideas? 
Thank you for answering!

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459488/change-content-of-uiwebview-div-object

Comment: Where is the HTML coming from?

Comment: Is coming from any web. The web view starts on google

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be done something like this:

```
-(void)setWebViewScale:(NSUInteger)pageScale {
     _textFontSize = pageScale;
    NSString *jsString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].style.webkitTextSizeAdjust= '%d%%'",pageScale];
    [_webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsString];
    [jsString release];
}
```

And +/- scale will done by:

```
- (IBAction)changeTextFontSize:(id)sender
{
    switch ([sender tag]) {
        case 1: // A-
            _textFontSize = (_textFontSize > MIN_PAGE_SCALE) ? _textFontSize - STEP_PAGE_SCALE : _textFontSize;
            break;
        case 2: // A+
            _textFontSize = (_textFontSize < MAX_PAGE_SCALE) ? _textFontSize + STEP_PAGE_SCALE : _textFontSize;
            break;
    }

    [self setWebViewScale:_textFontSize];
}
```

Defines MAX_PAGE_SCALE and MIN_PAGE_SCALE restricts content to be too big and too small, and STEP_PAGE_SCALE determine step of scale change.

Answer (score 0):

web views are used to display HTML, so if you control the HTML, or at least know its basic structure, you can use CSS to modify the style

Comment: OK! I don't know anything about CSS, but I understand that if I add it in any soucre-code of any web page, I would be able to control the size. Any ideas for the CSS code?

Comment: i dont know css so usually just trial and error, but i dont think this would work if you are allowing someone to view any site, really only works for controlled or known HTML